# What is the unique solution to this system of equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

The solution sets:

> -2x + 2y + 5z = -12 (A)
>
> 4x + 3y - Z = -8 (B)
>
> -5x + 3y - 4z = 7 (C)

I aligned Set A with Set B, multiplying set B by 5 to cancel out the z's:

> -2x + 2y + 5z = -12
>
> 20x + 15y -5z = -40
>
> 18x + 17y = -52 (D)

Next, I aligned Set B with Set C, multiplying Set B by 4 to cancel out the z's once more:

> -16x - 12y + 4z = -32
>
> -5x + 3y - 4z = 7
>
> -21x - 9y = - 25 (E)

Aligning Sets D & E I multiplied D by 21 and E by 18 to cancel the x's:

> 378x + 357y = -1092
>
> -378x - 162y = -450
>
> 195y = -1542/- 195

From this point I need assistance. Somewhere I believed I made a mistake but I do not know where.

Comment: It should be $-16 x - 12 y + 4 z = 32 $ not $-32$.

Comment: I got the solution as  $x = -1, y = -2, z = -2 $

Comment: @HosamHajjir Peace and thank you. Did you multiply it by 4?

Comment: I multiplied by $(-4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last equation has only $y$ as a variable, so find its value.  I can't read the formatting on the last line to say what the answer is.  Then plug that $y$ into $D$ or $E$ and you find $x$.  Now plug both $x,y$ into any of the first equations and you can find $z$.

When you aligned set B with set C you dropped a sign.  You multiplied by $-4$, not $4$, so the right side should be $32$.  A good way to find these is to follow the first paragraph to get a full solution.  It will satisfy your last equation.  Now plug it into each earlier equation and find where it fails.  That is the place you made the error.

Comment: I edited the format